# Mouse not detected in windows 7 virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, drivers, mouse, virtualization

I have a gaming mouse with programmable buttons and led-lights. I want to customize the mouse with some software which came with the mouse. I got it in cd-form, but I downloaded it from the store's website, so I have access to it.

The software that is ment to be used with the mouse is designed for Windows XP, Vista and 7 and 8. I use Linux on all machines, and I do not have access to any computers that run Windows on them. Therefore, to make it work, I have used VirtualBox to create a virtual machine running Windows 7. When I make changes to the mouse in Windows 7 virtual machine, the changes are stored on the mouse itself, so I can use it in linux afterwards.

When I got the mouse a while ago (before end of support for Windows 7 if that has anything to do with this), I managed to customize the mouse through the Windows 7 virtual machine. The problem is that when I now try to make some new changes, I get messages like this "Please connect mouse device to apply settings.", and I don't remember how to fix it. It might be I don't remember how I did it, but it might also be that something in Windows 7 OS has changed. I have searched for hours on the internet for solutions, and also tried to make a new clean virtual machine of Windows 7. It doesn't seem like Windows 7 has any problems with the mouse, but I can't figure out why then the mouse software doesn't detect it. Please help or I might not be able to change my mouse macros anymore.

When I am in the virtual machine, I also click in the virtualbox tab "devices", and then check the gaming mouse device so that it is connected to the guest OS.

I have also noticed that in "devices and printers", the "USB Laser Game Mouse", has the icon of a keyboard, not sure what this means. In the properties of the mouse, under general, it says "Categories: **Keyboard**, Mouse", but this is not a keyboard and a mouse, just a mouse right?

Comment: Once you connected the mouse, does it list as gaming mouse or generic mouse in the device manager? if the latter, its not passing the mouse through correctly. If the first, try removing the device, reboot, or try reinstalling the guest additions.

Comment: When I open in the device manager, it is listed under "Mice and other pointing devices" as a "HID-compliant mouse", and when I check "devices and printers", it shows up like a "USB Laser Game Mouse". I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: When I uninstalled the mouse device, it dissapeared from device manager, and when I rebooted, it appeared again, but it doesn't seem like something have changed, the gaming mouse software is still not detecting the mouse device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution!] I found a solution on my own after messing with this gaming mouse for probably 6 hours. The solution I am a little surprised I didn't think of is trying to run the mouse software in Windows 10. I made a virtual machine that runs Windows 10, and installed the mouse software, worked right out of the box, even though the mouse software were only ment for xp, vista, 7 and 8. Still worked on windows 10 as well.